# Capitalizing keys of each element in an object in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

I have this object:

```
{
'application': "BP 9ALT 8 123",
 'address': "935 HAMPTON CRES",
 'unit': null,
 'status': "COMPLETED -ALL INSP SIGNED OFF"
}
```

I want to make each key capitalized like:

```
{
 'Application': "BP 9ALT 8 123",
 'Address': "935 HAMPTON CRES",
 'Unit': null,
 'Status': "COMPLETED -ALL INSP SIGNED OFF"
}
```

What's an easy way to do it in Vuejs?

Comment: if you're outputting it into HTML, then filters (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html), if you want to just capitalize the keys in the object, then just for loop the keys and return a new object

Comment: Just to add a link, in case you don't know how to implement the second option suggested by @A.L: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution

```js
const object = {
  application: "BP 9ALT 8 123",
  address: "935 HAMPTON CRES",
  unit: null,
  status: "COMPLETED -ALL INSP SIGNED OFF",
};

const output = Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => [
  key[0].toUpperCase() + key.slice(1),
  value,
]);

console.log(Object.fromEntries(output));
```

See

- [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)
- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: ***On side note:-*** No need of splitting and joining you can simply do key.slice(1)

Comment: Thanks Code Maniac. Iterator. And no need of `join`

Comment: only thing is it won't do nested objects, not that the OP specified it, but you'd kind of expect it from a capitalizer of keys function

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.reduce()` and `String.toUpperCase()` like below

```js
var obj = {
 'application': "BP 9ALT 8 123",
 'address': "935 HAMPTON CRES",
 'unit': null,
 'status': "COMPLETED -ALL INSP SIGNED OFF"
}

var resultOne = Object.entries(obj).reduce(function(acc, value) {
  acc[value[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value[0].slice(1)] = value[1];
  return acc;
}, {});

// Updated

// In the reduce anonymous function, instead of value you can place [key, value]. So there will be no indexing
var resultTwo= Object.entries(obj).reduce(function(acc, [key, value]) {
  acc[key[0].toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});



console.log(resultOne);
console.log(resultTwo);
```

Comment: ***On side note:-*** Op wants only first character of key to be uppercased, your solution make whole key uppercased

Comment: @CodeManiac yes my mistake, updating it ;). Thanks for pointing it out